# eosiocpp -g generates empty abi file

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, eosiocpp

I have created smart contract inside the /build/contracts and running this comman generates empty abi file.

eosiocpp -g eosio.test.abi eosio.test.cpp

tried both hpp and cpp but same result.

Comment: Can you confirm your passing these actions into EOSIO_ABI? Add the code to the question as well perhaps.

Comment: try to add @abi table or action to your table or function header

Comment: Actually the code is based on eosio.token, I'm trying to play around with it.

EOSIO_ABI( eosio::test, (create)(issue)(transfer)(hi) )

Comment: There are lots of developers experiencing this issue, I wonder why and what is the common cause of this issue?

Comment: I don't think annotations are still necessary if you are using the EOSIO_ABI right?

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen to me last night.  Make sure the class name and your file names match.

In other words, if you're compiling the **hello** contract, make sure the file names are `hello.hpp` and `hello.cpp`.

Comment: ha! that was my problem too

Answer (score 2):

You could use of the newest macros:

> Added ACTION macro which is simply a shortcut for [[eosio::action]]
>   void.
>   Added TABLE macro which is simply a shortcut for struct
>   [[eosio::table]].
>   Added CONTRACT macro which is simply a shortcut for
>   class [[eosio::contract]].

Comment: why would I want to do that?

Comment: At the time of writing this eosio.cdt wasn't able to compile contracts without the macros. Currently I think it works both ways.

Answer (score 2):

When you're generating your ABI consider a few things:

1. Use the new command **eosio-cpp**

   For example:
   *eosio-cpp -I include -o my_contract.wasm my_contract.cpp -abigen*
2. Use the C++ 11 attributes included in the newest EOSIO version such as **[[eosio::action]]**, **[[eosio::table]]**, **[[eosio::contract]]**
3. If the contract structure is too complicated at this point "abigen" could fail to generate the ABI file. You should create it manually or eventually fix broken parts. Take a look at [Understanding ABI Files](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/the-abi) :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using one of the new CDTs

In my case the following command worked

```
eosio-abigen hello.cpp --contract=hello --output=hello.abi
```

Comment: odd.  that worked for me.  you'd think that --abigen would just call this internally and work just as well

Answer (score 1):

you need extra comments marked in hpp file to help eosiocpp generate concrete abi file. for actions, you need to add comment

`c++
//@abi action`

above its declaration. for multi_index table, you need to add comment

`c++
//@abi table <underlying class or struct name> (i64|i32)`

above the underlying class or struct definition.

Comment: what is the difference of i64 and i32? The primary key only receive uint64, right?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by an invalid contract name. If filename and contract class name do not match, `eosio-cpp` does not generate the abi.

If your file has the name `foobar` then your contract must also have the name `foobar`. If this is not the case you need to specify the `-contract=name` parameter.

Assuming your file is named `foobar.test.cpp` and your contract name is `foobar`, you need to compile with:

```
eosio-cpp -abigen fooobar.test.cpp -o foobar.wasm -contract=foobar
```